# My question is regarding gravitational potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, potential, potential-energy

If you take a spherical shell, say of mass $M$, and then you split the shell in 2 portions by a plane other than the median plane....say that the larger portion is A and the smaller portion is B....Now consider a point C, which is the centre of the circular common interface of both portions A and B.
Could you compare the gravitational field and potential by both the portions A and B at C.
Please provide a suitable explanation for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a straightforward application of Newton's Shell theorem. The gravitational field of the two portions exactly cancels out, and C does not have to be the centre of the common interface. I have given a proof in the caption of Figure 8.4 of [Structures of the Sky](https://www.troubador.co.uk/bookshop/computing-science-education/light-after-dark-i/)

[image]

> **Figure 8.4: Newton’s shell theorem (part I)**. It is a well known theorem of Euclidean
> geometry that, for points A, B, C & D on a circle centre O, angle A equals angle C
> and angle B equals angle D. So, triangles BAX and DCX are similar (the same shape but
> different sizes). Then the length of the small arcs AB and CD are proportional to their
> distance from X. On a sphere, similar areas at AB and at CD are proportional to the
> square of their distances from X. With a uniform spherical shell and an inverse square
> law, the gravitational force due to matter in a small region at AB is equal and opposite to
> the gravitational force due to matter at a similar region at CD. Since gravity cancels out
> for all such regions, there is no net gravitational force inside the shell.

Since there is no gravitational force inside the shell, the gravitational potential is constant inside the shell.

Comment: The question says “gravitational field *and potential*”, so this answers only half the question.

Comment: My main issue is regarding the relation between the gravitational potential at C wrt to A and B...like which is greater in magnitude..please help me out there

Comment: @JayprakashMundhra You can calculate the contributions from the two pieces by integrating. Have you tried?

Comment: @G.Smith,  As asked, this part of the question is meaningless, because only a single point was mentioned. As answered, no net gravitational force inside the shell means constant potential.

Comment: @CharlesFrancis I think the question is reasonably clear and certainly *not* meaningless: “Could you compare the gravitational ... potential by both the portions A and B at C.“

Comment: @CharlesFrancis In any case, you shouldn’t be answering homework-like questions. Four people have already voted to close the question, presumably as homework-like. I wouldn’t bother providing a complete answer because it might be deleted by a moderator.

Comment: @G.Smith, it is meaningful to compare gravitational fields, and it is clear from Newton's shell theorem that they cancel. Gravitational potential *only* has meaning because its derivative is the field. It has already been observed that sum of the potentials is constant inside the shell. Any further comparison is simply a comparison between the arbitrary constants in potential, and is patently meaningless.

Comment: @G.Smith, it wasn't so flagged when I answered, and I didn't interpret it as such.

Comment: @CharlesFrancis I would like a theoretical answer for the question and not indulge in some evasive calculations for the answer.

Comment: I have already given you a complete theoretical answer to the question. As @G.Smith has said, this is already probably too much. By an evasive calculation, do you mean to suggest that Newton did not formulate the subject but merely evaded it?